# Function in .psm1 not getting exported

Tags: powershell

I have a myFunc.psm1 file like this:

```
$ApiVersion = "201846465"
Export-ModuleMember -variable ApiVersion

function Get-Something {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Id]
    )
    process {
        # ...
}
```

When I import this to another setup.ps1 file, I saw this in execution:

```
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'D:\myFunc.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Importing variable 'ApiVersion'.
VERBOSE: Hi from setup.ps1
```

When I remove

```
$ApiVersion = "201846465"
Export-ModuleMember -variable ApiVersion
```

I can see:

```
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Get-Something'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-Something'.
VERBOSE: Hi from setup.ps1
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a `Export-ModuleMember` call inside a `*.psm1` file, all *functions and aliases*<sup>[1]</sup> are *automatically* exported - but *not  variables*.

**Once you use an `Export-ModuleMember` call, the automatic exporting is deactivated, and you must then explicitly name *all* elements to be exported - including functions and aliases.**

Therefore:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Variable ApiVersion -Function Get-Something
```

**Be sure to place the `Export-ModuleMember` call at the *bottom* of your file**, to make sure that all elements you want to export have already been defined - otherwise, they're ignored.

---

<sup>[1] Curiously, in *dynamic* modules created with `New-Module`, it is *functions only* (not also aliases) that are automatically exported.</sup>